# How to display XML content as dropdown menu in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Groups>
    <Group num="1">
        <GroupName>First Group</GroupName>
    </Group>
     <Group num="2">
        <GroupName>Second Group</GroupName>
    </Group>
</Groups>
```

Would like to display the GroupName's as a drop down menu in XSLT.

I tried the following and it shows empty drop down menu.

```
<SELECT NAME="Groups">                      
    <xsl:for-each select="Groups/Group">                            
        <OPTION VALUE="{GroupName}">
            <xsl:value-of select="GroupName"/>
        </OPTION>                           
    </xsl:for-each>
</SELECT>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your context. You didn't show the template where that `for-each` is operating. If it doesn't match the root node `/` it won't find the relative nodes and will be empty.

It will work with this stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <SELECT NAME="Groups">                      
            <xsl:for-each select="Groups/Group">                            
                <OPTION VALUE="{GroupName}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="GroupName"/>
                </OPTION>                           
            </xsl:for-each>
        </SELECT> 
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If it didn't work in your case, your `match` attribute is probably different. It's all a matter of context. If your template matches `Group`, then your `for-each` has to consider that context. This will also work:

```
<xsl:template match="Groups">
    <SELECT NAME="Groups">                      
        <xsl:for-each select="Group">                            
            <OPTION VALUE="{GroupName}">
                <xsl:value-of select="GroupName"/>
            </OPTION>                           
        </xsl:for-each>
    </SELECT> 
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you. My changes worked when I removed the template to the form. Earlier, I declared everything in a separate template and called it in the form.